# Setting the address attribute in an AWS Cognito user pool using an object

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

According to the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-attributes.html) the Cognito 'address' attibute should follow the [OpenID spec](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#AddressClaim), which allows for an object with fields:

```
formatted
    Full mailing address, formatted for display or use on a mailing label. This field MAY contain multiple lines, separated by newlines. Newlines can be represented either as a carriage return/line feed pair ("\r\n") or as a single line feed character ("\n"). 
street_address
    Full street address component, which MAY include house number, street name, Post Office Box, and multi-line extended street address information. This field MAY contain multiple lines, separated by newlines. Newlines can be represented either as a carriage return/line feed pair ("\r\n") or as a single line feed character ("\n"). 
locality
    City or locality component. 
region
    State, province, prefecture, or region component. 
postal_code
    Zip code or postal code component. 
country
    Country name component.
```

Is it possible in Cognito to set these fields? I tried setting the address with a stringified object, i.e., `JSON.stringify({"locality": "Auckland", "country": "New Zealand"})`. But when I returned the claims object from authorization at the AWS API gateway, I got the `address: { formatted: '{"locality":"Auckland","country":"New Zealand"}' }`. So it seems it is just taking whatever string I send it and setting that as the 'formatted' address.

I'm using the Amplify Auth api to interact with cognito.

Comment: Did u figure this out? Stuck with this issue myself..

Comment: No progress from me, I just ended up assuming that it only accepts strings.

Comment: Yep.. Using amplify and cognito SDK here. Using json.stringify({locality: "Auckland", country: "New Zealand"}) seems to have done the trick. When fetching user attributes on the client I get the expected result. JSON.parse(user.attributes.address) => {locality: "Auckland", country: "New Zealand"}